# How to pursue your interview status?

Tags: interviewing

I applied for a job, they instantly got back to me and made the first interview. They asked me if I am having other interviews with different companies, and I wasn't so I said no.

The second interview was held with a senior manager next week. The entire process took only 9 days.
After the second interview, the first recruiter asked how the second interview was. I told so. She told me that I will have another interview with a director soon, so I said OK.

Almost 2 weeks passed, no news, and I scheduled different interviews with other companies. I want this job, so should I drop them an e-mail and kindly tell that "I will have different interviews but on the other hand, I am looking forward to hear from them?" Will this be an appropriate to do so?

Comment: See [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses, The topic you shared will cover, but actually i make a statement and said i am only interviewing with them. Now there are different opportunities and companies for me. If i decide to ask about the status, should i also kindly mention about the new situation? Will this be an appropriate to do so?

Comment: "i make a statement and said i am only interviewing with them".  No worries, it's a non-issue.  They of course realize that after such an incredibly long period of time, you will be pursuing other opportunities.  Go ahead and send them a reminder email.  It makes no difference if you mention or don't mention the other interviews you are having, you won't be able to "rush" them either way.  Good luck!

Comment: Interviewing is not dating. Just because you're interviewing with one company doesn't mean you can't interview elsewhere. Maybe the initial interviewer asked you that just to get an idea of your job searching timetable.

Comment: Maybe i sholud have be more clear, my mistake. They asked about if i am interviewing with others, and i said no. Now i am having, so being clear maybe shows that i am acting ethicly about the issue, and looking forward to hear from them anyway. i hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During my internships I was constantly in this situation because the recruiters have a lot going on with travel and dozens of interviews so their individual communication can be thin.

This is a email I sent about 10 days after my interview:

> Hello Mr. Bob:
>
> I very much enjoyed the interview. I have one question.
>
> If possible, at what time will we be receiving a response about our interviews?
>
> Best of luck in the recruiting process, I look forward to hearing from you.

Occasionally, if needed, I will make a comment that other companies are waiting on my response. That kind of hints to them that they are not my only option.

They normally response promptly with a timeframe they will send out responses and that at least resolves some nerves.